# ViewModel with a SelectList and a LINQ Query result with a single reocrd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How can we populate a ViewModel with following two properties:

1. A `query result type` from a LINQ query that returns only a single record
2. A `SelectList` type

In other words, suppose we have a view that displays only a single movie based on the selected ID. And we want to assign a year of release to that movie from a dropdown list of years, how do I fill in the `????` in the following ViewModel and Controller?

**Note**: In the following ViewModel if I use myMovie property of type `IQueryable<Movie>` and assign this property of ViewModel to the query qrySingleMovie from following controller I get the error `the name qrySingleMovie does not exist in the current context`

**Models**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Year
{
  public int YearId {get; set;}
  public int MovieYear {get; set;}
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public ???? myMovie;
    public SelectList MovieReleaseYears;
    public int ReleasedYr { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int MovieID)
{
    // Use LINQ to get list of Release years.
    IQueryable<string> YearQuery = from m in _context.Years
                                    orderby m.MovieYear
                                    select m.MovieYear;

    //Following query selects only a single movie based on Primary Key ID
    var qrysingleMovie = from m in _context.Movies
                 where m.ID == movieID
                 select m;

    var movieReleaseYrVM = new MovieGenreViewModel();
    movieReleaseYrVM.MovieReleaseYears = new SelectList(await YearQuery.ToListAsync());
    movieReleaseYrVM.myMovie = ????

    return View(movieReleaseYrVM);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In my real project, the model has lots of properties and the corresponding **View** also displays most of those properties. I was thinking if there is a simpler way to define a ViewModel that does not contain all the properties of the model such as this [ASP.NET Article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search.html) defines a view model `MovieGenreViewModel` but there they are using List and in their View they are iterating through multiple Movies. I'm trying to mimic their example but in my case it's a single record (not the list of records) with a `SelectList`. How can I mimic that kind of scenario with a single record and not be able to include in View Model tons of model properties that model has?

Comment: How about `public Movie myMovie;` and `movieReleaseYrVM.myMovie = qrysingleMovie.Single();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update a Movie record, all you need to get the movie record is it's unique Id. So why not add a MovieId property to your view model. If you prefer to show the MovieName in the UI, you may add a `MovieName` property as well.

**Remember view models are specific to views. It is not necessary to mimic your entire entity model when you create a view model. Add only those properties your view absolutely need.**

```
public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public int MovieId;
    public string MovieName { set;get;}
    public SelectList MovieReleaseYears;
    public int ReleasedYr { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your GET action set these property values.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int MovieID)
{
    var vm = new MovieGenreViewModel();

    var movie =  _context.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==movieID);

    if(movie==null)
       return Content("Movie not found"); // to do :Return a view with "not found" message

    IQueryable<string> YearQuery = from m in _context.Years
                                    orderby m.MovieYear
                                    select m.MovieYear;   

    // set the property values. 
    vm .MovieReleaseYears = new SelectList(await YearQuery.ToListAsync());
    vm .MovieId= movie.ID;
    vm .MovieName= movie.Name;

    return View(vm );
}
```

Now in your view, you keep the movie id in a hidden field so that when you submit the form, it will be submitted to the HttpPost action method which handles the form submit.

```
@model MovieGenreViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("AssignYear","Home"))
{
    <p>@Model.MovieName</p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.MovieId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(d=>d.ReleasedYr, Model.MovieReleaseYears)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

You can use the same view model as your `AssignYear` action method parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AssignYear(MovieGenreViewModel model)
{
  // check model.MovieId and model.ReleasedYr
  // to do : Save data and return something
}
```

If you do not prefer to add only those properties needed by the view to the view model, but want to show a tons of properties of the Movie, you may consider adding a new property of type `Movie` to your view model

```
public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public Movie Movie { set;get;}
    public SelectList MovieReleaseYears;
    public int ReleasedYr { get; set; }
}
```

Your existing LINQ statement returns a collection of one element. You cannot assign a collection of Movies to a property of type Movie. You may use the FirstOrDefault() method to get a single object.

```
var movie =  _context.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==movieID);
 //After null check
vm.Movie = movie;
```

Comment: After reading your suggested solution I've added an UPDATE section to my post. In my my real project, the model has tons of properties and I'm trying to find a shorter route to display those properties in the View along with some dropdowns that come from different tables (entities).

Comment: you want all those tons of properties in the view ? as i said earlier, the view model should contain properties absolutely needed by the view.

Comment: Unfortunately the customer wants the corresponding page to display all these fields (properties) that are in the table (Model) per ID selected - along with some dropdownlists

Comment: You can add a property of type `Movie` and assign that and use as needed.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. But when I assign that property to a LINQ query you suggested in your response, I get the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'myProject.Models.Movie' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<myProject.Models.Movie>'` How can I resolve this error?. It seems your suggestion is very close to what I am trying to do.

Comment: because your code will try to return a collection of one item. replace that with the `FirstOrDefault` call from my `answer._context.Movies.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==movieID);` This will return a single Movie object, not a collection with one item.

Comment: your suggestion in the above comment worked (thank you). Do you need to make any changes in your post or that is still valid even if we have tons of properties to display? If not, you may want to update your post based on my UPDATE section; otherwise, I will mark your post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why can´t you use Movie as the type for your "myMovie" property ?
Then you can use that object to display the name for example.ie **movie.Name**.
You can also store the movieId in a hidden field so when you post back it will be available for you to use in the server side.
You can use LINQ to retrieve that object from the database like so:

```
var qrysingleMovie = _context.Movies.Single(m=> m.ID == movieID);
```

Alternatively you can use 2 properties instead of the whole object. One for the title ie: string MovieName and another one for the id int MovieId

```
public string MovieName  { get; set; }
public int MovieId  { get; set; }
```

Note: Bear in mind that using "Single" means that you need to have the movie in the database otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'myProject.Models.Movie' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<myProject.Models.Movie>'`

Comment: Please see the documentation here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx

_Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence._

Or you can either use SingleOrDefault<TSource> that basically return null if it does not find the record.

_Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence._